# Generic solution to merge iterables such as lists, tuples and sets

Tags: python, collections, append, concatenation, containers

I am searching for a pythonic and clean way to merge iterables in a generic form, without even knowing their types.

```
>>> l = [0, 1]
>>> t = (2, 3)
>>> s = {4, 5}
```

I can cast all into a `list` and concatenate them for exemple:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for it in (l, t, s):
...     res += it
... 
>>> res
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So you end up with an utility function like this:

```
def merge_it(*args):
    res = []
    for it in args:
        res += list(it)
    return res
```

But it doesn't feel that good... Is there something more elegant to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `itertools.chain` to do that:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [0, 1]
>>> t = (2, 3)
>>> s = {4, 5}
>>> list(chain(l, t, s))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```